# Can't get to the bottom of the content with my scrollview

Tags: android, xml, scrollview

I have my xml file. It is a RelativeLayout with a ScrollView and inside the ScrollView I have LinearLayout and many more. The problem is that I can't reach the end of the view, as you can see it end with a "Sign Up" button... But my view is cut by the scroll and I can just see the middle of the button, the other middle is off screen.

So, any suggestions for how can I fix this? How can I work with the ScrollView so it wraps all of my content...

Check it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/bg_signup"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".SignUp">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:background="@xml/signup_round">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="260dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@xml/border_lines"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/new_signup" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                    android:text="@string/signup"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorRB"
                    android:textSize="26sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/first_name_EditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-25dp"
                android:hint="@string/first_name"
                android:textColor="@color/colorRB" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/last_name_EditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:hint="@string/last_name"
                android:textColor="@color/colorRB" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/email_EditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:hint="@string/email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:textColor="@color/colorRB" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/email_confirmation_EditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:hint="@string/email_confirmation"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:textColor="@color/colorRB" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password_EditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:hint="@string/password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textColor="@color/colorRB" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password_confirmation_EditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:hint="@string/password_confirmation"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textColor="@color/colorRB" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@xml/border_lines"
                android:text="@string/sex"
                android:textColor="@color/colorRB"
                android:textSize="26sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/sex_spinner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="-25dp"
                android:entries="@array/sex_array" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@xml/border_lines"
                android:text="@string/brithday"
                android:textColor="@color/colorRB"
                android:textSize="26sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="-35dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/birthdayBtn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0"
                    android:background="@color/fbutton_color_transparent"
                    android:onClick="showDatePickerDialog"
                    android:text="@string/birthdayBtn"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorRB" />

                <Space
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/dateSelectedTv"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0"
                    android:text="--/--/--"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorRB"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/terms_conditions"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorRB"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <CheckBox
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@xml/button_round"
                android:onClick=""
                android:text="@string/signup"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick=""
    android:src="@drawable/close_signup" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: the attribute 'orientation =vertical' has no sense in relativelayout??

Comment: what is the RelativeLayout for ? it only contains the LinearLayout right ? 
Try removing the RelativeLayout and make sure Scrollview's height matches parents and not wraps content

Comment: Thanks, it works.. I removed the RelativeLayout and everything works perfect!